# How to use Xamarin free trial license in offline enviroment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2015, offline

I'm currently developing in an *Amazon Workspace* which doesn't have any internet connection. In *Visual Studio 2015* I installed **Xamarin** and now I just want to start coding using a free trial license. The thing is I really don't know how. When I open my project I get to see this, and of course I can't register nor login because I don't have access to internet.

[image: xamarin]

In my account dashboard I don't have any computer linked to my account.

[image]

So how do I use the free trial with my offline workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Android Licenses via: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/offline_activation/

> If you do not have internet access on the machine you're trying to
>   activate, you will need to contact Xamarin Support with details of
>   your machine. You can then obtain a license file via your Xamarin
>   store account, provided you have purchased a license.
>
> If you login to
>   https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/computers and click
>   License next to the machine, you'll get a link to download the license
>   file.
>
> Offline Activation on Windows After obtaining a  monoandroid.licx
>   file, it must be placed in the appropriate directory.
>
> Windows Vista/Windows 7 Create the directory  %ProgramData%\Mono for
>   Android\License, and place the  monoandroid.licx file into that
>   directory (thus creating the file e.g.  C:\ProgramData\Mono for
>   Android\License\monoandroid.licx). Once this file has been created,
>   you should be able to use Xamarin.Android normally.
>
> Trial Licenses Trial licenses have the word trial embedded in the
>   filename, eg. monoandroid.trial.licx, but otherwise the instructions
>   are the same.
>
> Offline Activation on Mac OS X When you receive your license file, you
>   should save it to the  $HOME/Library/MonoAndroid folder, creating the
>   file  $HOME/Library/MonoAndroid/License.
>
> Trial Licenses Trial licenses have the word trial added to the
>   filename, eg. License.trial, but otherwise the instructions are the
>   same.
>
> Once the license has been saved to disk, Xamarin.Android installation
>   and activation should complete successfully.